# Check if an integer is within the next 5 increments in SQL, when the numbers can wrap

Tags: sql, sql-server, range

Let's suppose I have a range of numbers, 0 to 59.

I need to check if at any given number, there is data at an index (in the range) within the next 5 increments.

Example:

If I'm at index 57, and there's data at 02 - I need to check 57 + 5, but for it to wrap back after 59, back to 0.

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL Server?

```
select * from Table1 where index between 57 and 02.
```

The above is an idea of what I'm trying to do, but that just checks numbers from 02 to 57, not wrapping the way I intend.

EDIT 1:

Imagine it's seconds in a minute.
And it's values in a column called ID.

If I want to check a row in Table1 whether the value in the ID column is between 57 seconds and 2 seconds, how would I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking but `(57 + 5) % 60` evaluates to 2. % is the mod operator and `a % b` returns the remainder result of dividing `a / b`

Comment: @DavidDubois 0 to 59. Start at 0 but as soon as you were to hit 60 it goes back to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment, not not super clear what youre asking, but if @idx was 57, then this would get any data that was at 57, 58, 59, 00, 01 or 02 (well, apart from the fact that 02 as a number is just `2`, so if index is a varchar of literally `02` some adjustment will be required)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE index in (
  @idx, 
  (@idx+1)%60, 
  (@idx+2)%60, 
  (@idx+3)%60, 
  (@idx+4)%60,
  (@idx+5)%60
)
```

Tweak the additions if your index is 1 - 60 instead of 0 - 59. This is easiest done by subbing 1 off the index so it becomes 0-59 instead of 1-60:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE index-1 in (
  @idx, 
  (@idx+1)%60, 
  (@idx+2)%60, 
  (@idx+3)%60, 
  (@idx+4)%60,
  (@idx+5)%60
)
```

Basically, remember that the mod operator always returns a number between 0 and one less than the divisor, so `x % 1000` is guaranteed to return between 0 and 999 (inclusive)

Comment: I commented before I read your answer :) This solves it thank you. I'll accept it when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after, I think?

```
DECLARE @Start int;
SET @Start = 57;

WITH T AS(
    SELECT CASE (@Start + V.I) % 60 WHEN 0 THEN 60 ELSE (@Start + V.I) % 60 END AS I
    FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) V(I))
SELECT *
FROM YourTable YT
WHERE [Index] IN (SELECT I FROM T);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do a separate comparison for each id.  Just use arithmetic:

```
where (index >= @idx and index <= @idx + 5) or
      (@idx + 5 >= 60 and index <= (@idx + 5) - 60)
```

What is convenient about this expression is that it works for any range of values, without having to expand the expression.